# Getting notices on fresh 3.6.1 install

Tags: errors, debug, warnings, notices

I'm a relative newcomer to WP. I've been playing around for the past 3 months or so trying out themes, plugins etc. About a month ago I got to the point where I turned debug on and I started seeing error message and notices in my dashboard. So research suggested that at least some of these my have been the result of disabled plugins that didn't clean up after themselves.

I'm at the point where I'm going to get serious about building a site so I blew away my install. Cleared my browser cache and cookies. Used phpmyadmin to recreate the database. Uploaded a fresh version of WP 3.6.1. Recreated the wp-config file. Logged in and I still see the following in the recent comments section:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /usr/home/mysitename/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line
>   1120
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /usr/home/mysitename/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line
>   1124
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /usr/home/mysitename/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line
>   1126
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /usr/home/mysitename/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line
>   1127
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /usr/home/mysitename/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line
>   1127
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /usr/home/mysitename/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line
>   1130
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /usr/home/mysitename/public_html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line
>   1130

Can anyone help make this go away? What am I missing?

Comment: Since it clearly doesn't happen for _everyone_ on WP 3.6.1, _something_ in your install must be leftover or otherwise broken. It is hard to guess what could that be.

Answer (score 0):

First: Good girl/guy! Debugging is important :) Second: As those are PHP errors, there still has to be something that causes those errors. And it's *not* DB related. Please turn off ***all*** plugins and switch to the default theme. If these errors still occur, then something happened during installation. Please go into your Dashboard and reinstall WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. The problem is that this is a fresh install so there were no plugins and all that is there is the default theme. I manually deleted everything in the public_html directory, I re-downloaded WP 3.6.1, I ftped it into the public_html directory. I used the WP install procedure to regenerate the wp-config.php file.  I copied it from the browser into my text editor, change debug to true, save and ftp to the server. Login and get the notices above.  (guy btw)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to have been related to the default comment that is included in the WP install.  Once I deleted the comment the error messages went away.